# Reaching data limit with AWS Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am playing around with some SQL code to implement a basic model I've been working on for a company I have recently joined. In doing so, one of my SQL queries reached my data disk limit and it returned an error explaining this. My question is, is my running complicated, large models impeding the company's other applications on Redshift? Does my company get a notification that I have gone over my limit?

EDIT: The SQL query was a number of nested SQL queries. The error code was error:  Disk Full
  code:      1016

Comment: if they want they can track the utilization and get the info .There are certain rules which can be implemented to get such notification

Comment: Please provide more information -- what were you doing (please be detailed) and what was the actual error message?

Comment: Thanks, added more info in body.

Comment: It seems data fetched in your nested sqls is too much to process (because of joins date size will increase) with configured memory, so it will start using disk space as intermediate buffer/storage. You may optimize your query or increase your cluster size. 
PS: Yes, your queries might definitely halt any other processes using redshift at same time.

Comment: Instead of multiple subqueries, try splitting it into multiple statements and staging the subqueries into tables first before joining them together to get the final result.

Answer (score 1):

First, try running this without running any other queries at the same time:

```
select
 sum(capacity)/1024 as capacity_gbytes
,sum(used)/1024 as used_gbytes
,(sum(capacity) - sum(used))/1024 as free_gbytes 
from stv_partitions where part_begin=0;
```

that will show you the amount of free disk space that you have.

My guess is that if your free space amount is fairly large you can be getting that error if you use `ORDER BY` in a statement that selects a lot of data (subquery or final query, it doesn't matter). In this case, all your data is sent to the leader node causing disk overflow. Rewriting the statement without `ORDER BY` will help.